# error: too many parameters Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Tags: java, android

this is my first time experience this. I need help with my issue in my constructor with this tons of parameters. For how exactly the best to do this, so I can pass all the value into my database method. This is my error

```
Error:(530, 12) error: too many parameters
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

I have seen some questions, but I can not understand it. Sorry to put so much code. Just want to make it clear. Thank You

```
public class ItemsDetailsSS {

private int unitID;
private int jaringanID;
private int tipeInspeksiID;

private int bushingBersih;

private int bodyBersih;
private int bodyBerdebu;
private int bodyBerminyak;
private int bodyBerkarat;
private int bodyLainnya;
private String bodyKeterangan;


public ItemsDetailsSS() {
    super();
}

public ItemsDetailsSS(int unitID, int garduID, String tanggalInspeksi, int tipeInspeksiID,
                      int bushingBersih, int bushingBerdebu, int bushingBerlumut, int bushingRetak, int bushingLainnya, String bushingKeterangan, int bodyBersih, int bodyBerdebu, int bodyBerminyak, int bodyBerkarat, int bodyLainnya, String bodyKeterangan,
                      int karetbushingBaik, int karetbushingRetak, int karetbushingPecah, int karetbushingLainnya, String karetbushingKeterangan, String karetbushingSuhuWBP,
                      int arresterfasaRBaik, int arresterfasaRPecah, int arresterfasaRTidakAda, int arresterfasaRLainnya, String arresterfasaRKeterangan,
                      int arresterfasaSBaik, int arresterfasaSPecah, int arresterfasaSTidakAda, int arresterfasaSLainnya, String arresterfasaSKeterangan,
                      int arresterfasaTBaik, int arresterfasaTPecah, int arresterfasaTTidakAda, int arresterfasaTLainnya, String arresterfasaTKeterangan,
                      int fusecutoutfasaRBaik, int fusecutoutfasaRPecah, int fusecutoutfasaRTidakAda, int fusecutoutfasaRLainnya, String fusecutoutfasaRKeterangan,
                      int fusecutoutfasaSBaik, int fusecutoutfasaSPecah, int fusecutoutfasaSTidakAda, int fusecutoutfasaSLainnya, String fusecutoutfasaSKeterangan,
                      int fusecutoutfasaTBaik, int fusecutoutfasaTPecah, int fusecutoutfasaTTidakAda, int fusecutoutfasaTLainnya, String fusecutoutfasaTKeterangan,
                      int phbtrpintuBaik, int phbtrpintuRusak, int phbtrpintuBerkarat, int phbtrpintuLainnya, String phbtrpintuKeterangan,
                      int phbtrlantaiBaik, int phbtrlantaiRusak, int phbtrlantaiBerlubang, int phbtrlantaiBerkarat, int phbtrlantaiLainnya, String phbtrlantaiKeterangan,
                      int phbtrdindingBaik, int phbtrdindingRusak, int phbtrdindingBerkarat, int phbtrdindingBerlubang, int phbtrdindingLainnya, String phbtrdindingKeterangan,
                      int phbtrengselBaik, int phbtrengselRusak, int phbtrengselBerkarat, int phbtrengselLainnya, String phbtrengselKeterangan,
                      int phbtrkunciBaik, int phbtrkunciRusak, int phbtrkunciTidakAda, int phbtrkunciLainnya, String phbtrkunciKeterangan,
                      int lbsonloadBaik, int lbsonloadRusak, int lbsonloadTidakAda, int lbsonloadLainnya, String lbsonloadArusBeban, String lbsonloadKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan1fasaRBaik, int nhfusejurusan1fasaRPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan1fasaRTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan1fasaRLainnya, String jurusan1fasaRArusBeban, String jurusan1fasaRKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan1fasaSBaik, int nhfusejurusan1fasaSPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan1fasaSTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan1fasaSLainnya, String jurusan1fasaSArusBeban, String jurusan1fasaSKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan1fasaTBaik, int nhfusejurusan1fasaTPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan1fasaTTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan1fasaTLainnya, String jurusan1fasaTArusBeban, String jurusan1fasaTKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan2fasaRBaik, int nhfusejurusan2fasaRPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan2fasaRTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan2fasaRLainnya, String jurusan2fasaRArusBeban, String jurusan2fasaRKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan2fasaSBaik, int nhfusejurusan2fasaSPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan2fasaSTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan2fasaSLainnya, String jurusan2fasaSArusBeban, String jurusan2fasaSKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan2fasaTBaik, int nhfusejurusan2fasaTPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan2fasaTTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan2fasaTLainnya, String jurusan2fasaTArusBeban, String jurusan2fasaTKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan3fasaRBaik, int nhfusejurusan3fasaRPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan3fasaRTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan3fasaRLainnya, String jurusan3fasaRArusBeban, String jurusan3fasaRKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan3fasaSBaik, int nhfusejurusan3fasaSPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan3fasaSTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan3fasaSLainnya, String jurusan3fasaSArusBeban, String jurusan3fasaSKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan3fasaTBaik, int nhfusejurusan3fasaTPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan3fasaTTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan3fasaTLainnya, String jurusan3fasaTArusBeban, String jurusan3fasaTKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan4fasaRBaik, int nhfusejurusan4fasaRPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan4fasaRTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan4fasaRLainnya, String jurusan4fasaRArusBeban, String jurusan4fasaRKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan4fasaSBaik, int nhfusejurusan4fasaSPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan4fasaSTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan4fasaSLainnya, String jurusan4fasaSArusBeban, String jurusan4fasaSKeterangan,
                      int nhfusejurusan4fasaTBaik, int nhfusejurusan4fasaTPutusSBL, int nhfusejurusan4fasaTTidakAda, int nhfusejurusan4fasaTLainnya, String jurusan4fasaTArusBeban, String jurusan4fasaTKeterangan,
                      int kabelutamaLVTC, String nilaikabelutamaLVTC, int kabelutamaLVTCBaik, int kabelutamaLVTCTerbakar, int kabelutamaLVTCRusakLuka,
                      int kabeljurusan1LVTC, String nilaikabeljurusan1LVTC, int kabeljurusan1NYY, String nilaikabeljurusan1NYY, int kabeljurusan1LVTCNYYBaik,
                      int kabeljurusan1LVTCNYYTerbakar, int kabeljurusan1LVTCNYYRusakLuka,
                      int kabeljurusan2LVTC, String nilaikabeljurusan2LVTC, int kabeljurusan2NYY, String nilaikabeljurusan2NYY,
                      int kabeljurusan2LVTCNYYBaik, int kabeljurusan2LVTCNYYTerbakar, int kabeljurusan2LVTCNYYRusakLuka,
                      int kabeljurusan3LVTC, String nilaikabeljurusan3LVTC,
                      int kabeljurusan3NYY, String nilaikabeljurusan3NYY, int kabeljurusan3LVTCNYYBaik, int kabeljurusan3LVTCNYYTerbakar, int kabeljurusan3LVTCNYYRusakLuka,
                      int kabeljurusan4LVTC, String nilaikabeljurusan4LVTC, int kabeljurusan4NYY, String nilaikabeljurusan4NYY,
                      int kabeljurusan4LVTCNYYBaik, int kabeljurusan4LVTCNYYTerbakar, int kabeljurusan4LVTCNYYRusakLuka,
                      int kabeljurusan1Baik, int kabeljurusan1Lainnya, String kabeljurusan1Keterangan,
                      int kabeljurusan2Baik, int kabeljurusan2Lainnya, String kabeljurusan2Keterangan,
                      int kabeljurusan3Baik, int kabeljurusan3Lainnya, String kabeljurusan3Keterangan,
                      int kabeljurusan4Baik, int kabeljurusan4Lainnya, String kabeljurusan4Keterangan,
                      int ardearresterBaik, int ardearresterTidakAda, int ardearresterLainnya, String ardearrester,
                      int ardebodytrafoBaik, int ardebodytrafoTidakAda, int ardebodytrafoLainnya, String bodytrafo,
                      int ardearresterbodytrafoGabung, int ardearresterbodytrafoTerpisah, String ardearresterbodytrafo,
                      int tapconnector, int bimetalpress, int lainnya, String sambunganjurusanKeterangan,
                      int tianggarduBeton, int tianggarduBesi, int tianggarduPortal, int tianggarduCantol,
                      int pipapudingBesi, int pipapudingPlastik, int pipapudingBaik, int pipapudingRusak,
                      int dudukantrafopagarBaik, int dudukantrafopagarRusak, int dudukantrafopagarTidakAda, int dudukantrafopagarLainnya,
                      String dudukantrafopagarKeterangan, int dudukantrafobordressBaik, int dudukantrafobordressRusak, int dudukantrafobordressTidakAda, int dudukantrafobordressLainnya,
                      String dudukantrafobordressKeterangan, int dudukantrafodudukanBaik, int dudukantrafodudukanRusak, int dudukantrafodudukanTidakAda, int dudukantrafodudukanLainnya,
                      String dudukantrafodudukanKeterangan, int sepatukabelkabelutamaBaik, int sepatukabelkabelutamaRusak, String sepatukabelkabelutama,
                      int sepatukabelkabeljurusanBaik, int sepatukabelkabeljurusanRusak, String sepatukabelkabeljurusan,
                      int busbarBaik, int busbarRusak, String busbar,
                      String fasaRUtamaLWBP, String fasaSUtamaLWBP, String fasaTUtamaLWBP, String fasaNUtamaLWBP,
                      String fasaRJurusan1LWBP, String fasaRJurusan2LWBP, String fasaRJurusan3LWBP, String fasaRJurusan4LWBP,
                      String fasaSJurusan1LWBP, String fasaSJurusan2LWBP, String fasaSJurusan3LWBP, String fasaSJurusan4LWBP,
                      String fasaTJurusan1LWBP, String fasaTJurusan2LWBP, String fasaTJurusan3LWBP, String fasaTJurusan4LWBP,
                      String fasaNJurusan1LWBP, String fasaNJurusan2LWBP, String fasaNJurusan3LWBP, String fasaNJurusan4LWBP,
                      String RSLWBP, String STLWBP, String TRLWBP, String RNLWBP, String SNLWBP, String TNLWBP,
                      String fasaRUtamaWBP, String fasaRJurusan1WBP, String fasaRJurusan2WBP, String fasaRJurusan3WBP, String fasaRJurusan4WBP,
                      String fasaSUtamaWBP, String fasaSJurusan1WBP, String fasaSJurusan2WBP, String fasaSJurusan3WBP, String fasaSJurusan4WBP,
                      String fasaTUtamaWBP, String fasaTJurusan1WBP, String fasaTJurusan2WBP, String fasaTJurusan3WBP, String fasaTJurusan4WBP,
                      String fasaNUtamaWBP, String fasaNJurusan1WBP, String fasaNJurusan2WBP, String fasaNJurusan3WBP, String fasaNJurusan4WBP,
                      String tegangangarduRSWBP, String tegangangarduSTWBP, String tegangangarduTRWBP, String tegangangarduRNWBP, String tegangangarduSNWBP, String tegangangarduTNWBP,
                      String teganganujungJaringan1R, String teganganujungJaringan1RIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan1S, String teganganujungJaringan1SIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan1T, String teganganujungJaringan1TIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan2R, String teganganujungJaringan2RIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan2S, String teganganujungJaringan2SIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan2T, String teganganujungJaringan2TIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan3R, String teganganujungJaringan3RIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan3S, String teganganujungJaringan3SIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan3T, String teganganujungJaringan3TIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan4R, String teganganujungJaringan4RIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan4S, String teganganujungJaringan4SIDPel,
                      String teganganujungJaringan4T, String teganganujungJaringan4TIDPel
) {

    this.unitID = unitID;
    this.garduID = garduID;
    this.tanggalInspeksi = tanggalInspeksi;
    this.tipeInspeksiID = tipeInspeksiID;


this.kabeljurusan2LVTC = kabeljurusan2LVTC;
    this.nilaikabeljurusan2LVTC = nilaikabeljurusan2LVTC;
    this.kabeljurusan2NYY = kabeljurusan2NYY;
    this.nilaikabeljurusan2NYY = nilaikabeljurusan2NYY;
    this.kabeljurusan2LVTCNYYBaik = kabeljurusan2LVTCNYYBaik;
    this.kabeljurusan2LVTCNYYTerbakar = kabeljurusan2LVTCNYYTerbakar;
    this.kabeljurusan2LVTCNYYRusakLuka = kabeljurusan2LVTCNYYRusakLuka;

    this.kabeljurusan3LVTC = kabeljurusan3LVTC;
    this.nilaikabeljurusan3LVTC = nilaikabeljurusan3LVTC;
    this.kabeljurusan3NYY = kabeljurusan3NYY;
    this.nilaikabeljurusan3NYY = nilaikabeljurusan3NYY;
    this.kabeljurusan3LVTCNYYBaik = kabeljurusan3LVTCNYYBaik;
    this.kabeljurusan3LVTCNYYTerbakar = kabeljurusan3LVTCNYYTerbakar;
    this.kabeljurusan3LVTCNYYRusakLuka = kabeljurusan3LVTCNYYRusakLuka;


    this.kabeljurusan4LVTC = kabeljurusan4LVTC;
    this.nilaikabeljurusan4LVTC = nilaikabeljurusan4LVTC;
    this.kabeljurusan4NYY = kabeljurusan4NYY;
    this.nilaikabeljurusan4NYY = nilaikabeljurusan4NYY;
    this.kabeljurusan4LVTCNYYBaik = kabeljurusan4LVTCNYYBaik;
    this.kabeljurusan4LVTCNYYTerbakar = kabeljurusan4LVTCNYYTerbakar;
    this.kabeljurusan4LVTCNYYRusakLuka = kabeljurusan4LVTCNYYRusakLuka;

    this.kabeljurusan1Baik = kabeljurusan1Baik;
    this.kabeljurusan1Lainnya = kabeljurusan1Lainnya;
    this.kabeljurusan1Keterangan = kabeljurusan1Keterangan;

    this.kabeljurusan2Baik = kabeljurusan2Baik;
    this.kabeljurusan2Lainnya = kabeljurusan2Lainnya;
    this.kabeljurusan2Keterangan = kabeljurusan2Keterangan;

    this.kabeljurusan3Baik = kabeljurusan3Baik;
    this.kabeljurusan3Lainnya = kabeljurusan3Lainnya;
    this.kabeljurusan3Keterangan = kabeljurusan3Keterangan;

    this.kabeljurusan4Baik = kabeljurusan4Baik;
    this.kabeljurusan4Lainnya = kabeljurusan4Lainnya;
    this.kabeljurusan4Keterangan = kabeljurusan4Keterangan;

    this.ardearresterBaik = ardearresterBaik;
    this.ardearresterTidakAda = ardearresterTidakAda;
    this.ardearresterLainnya = ardearresterLainnya;
    this.ardearrester = ardearrester;

    this.ardebodytrafoBaik = ardebodytrafoBaik;
    this.ardebodytrafoTidakAda = ardebodytrafoTidakAda;
    this.ardebodytrafoLainnya = ardebodytrafoLainnya;
    this.bodytrafo = bodytrafo;

    this.ardearresterbodytrafoGabung = ardearresterbodytrafoGabung;
    this.ardearresterbodytrafoTerpisah = ardearresterbodytrafoTerpisah;
    this.ardearresterbodytrafo = ardearresterbodytrafo;

    this.tapconnector = tapconnector;
    this.bimetalpress = bimetalpress;
    this.lainnya = lainnya;
    this.sambunganjurusanKeterangan = sambunganjurusanKeterangan;

    this.tianggarduBeton = tianggarduBeton;
    this.tianggarduBesi = tianggarduBesi;
    this.tianggarduPortal = tianggarduPortal;
    this.tianggarduCantol = tianggarduCantol;

    this.pipapudingBesi = pipapudingBesi;
    this.pipapudingPlastik = pipapudingPlastik;
    this.pipapudingBaik = pipapudingBaik;
    this.pipapudingRusak = pipapudingRusak;

    this.dudukantrafopagarBaik = dudukantrafopagarBaik;
    this.dudukantrafopagarRusak = dudukantrafopagarRusak;
    this.dudukantrafopagarTidakAda = dudukantrafopagarTidakAda;
    this.dudukantrafopagarLainnya = dudukantrafopagarLainnya;
    this.dudukantrafopagarKeterangan = dudukantrafopagarKeterangan;

    this.dudukantrafobordressBaik = dudukantrafobordressBaik;
    this.dudukantrafobordressRusak = dudukantrafobordressRusak;
    this.dudukantrafobordressTidakAda = dudukantrafobordressTidakAda;
    this.dudukantrafobordressLainnya = dudukantrafobordressLainnya;
    this.dudukantrafobordressKeterangan = dudukantrafobordressKeterangan;

    this.dudukantrafodudukanBaik = dudukantrafodudukanBaik;
    this.dudukantrafodudukanRusak = dudukantrafodudukanRusak;
    this.dudukantrafodudukanTidakAda = dudukantrafodudukanTidakAda;
    this.dudukantrafodudukanLainnya = dudukantrafodudukanLainnya;
    this.dudukantrafodudukanKeterangan = dudukantrafodudukanKeterangan;

    this.sepatukabelkabelutamaBaik = sepatukabelkabelutamaBaik;
    this.sepatukabelkabelutamaRusak = sepatukabelkabelutamaRusak;
    this.sepatukabelkabelutama = sepatukabelkabelutama;

    this.sepatukabelkabeljurusanBaik = sepatukabelkabeljurusanBaik;
    this.sepatukabelkabeljurusanRusak = sepatukabelkabeljurusanRusak;
    this.sepatukabelkabeljurusan = sepatukabelkabeljurusan;

    this.busbarBaik = busbarBaik;
    this.busbarRusak = busbarRusak;
    this.busbar = busbar;

    this.fasaRUtamaLWBP = fasaRUtamaLWBP;
    this.fasaRJurusan1LWBP = fasaRJurusan1LWBP;
    this.fasaRJurusan2LWBP = fasaRJurusan2LWBP;
    this.fasaRJurusan3LWBP = fasaRJurusan3LWBP;
    this.fasaRJurusan4LWBP = fasaRJurusan4LWBP;

    this.fasaSUtamaLWBP = fasaSUtamaLWBP;
    this.fasaSJurusan1LWBP = fasaSJurusan1LWBP;
    this.fasaSJurusan2LWBP = fasaSJurusan2LWBP;
    this.fasaSJurusan3LWBP = fasaSJurusan3LWBP;
    this.fasaSJurusan4LWBP = fasaSJurusan4LWBP;

    this.fasaTUtamaLWBP = fasaTUtamaLWBP;
    this.fasaTJurusan1LWBP = fasaTJurusan1LWBP;
    this.fasaTJurusan2LWBP = fasaTJurusan2LWBP;
    this.fasaTJurusan3LWBP = fasaTJurusan3LWBP;
    this.fasaTJurusan4LWBP = fasaTJurusan4LWBP;

    this.fasaNUtamaLWBP = fasaNUtamaLWBP;
    this.fasaNJurusan1LWBP = fasaNJurusan1LWBP;
    this.fasaNJurusan2LWBP = fasaNJurusan2LWBP;
    this.fasaNJurusan3LWBP = fasaNJurusan3LWBP;
    this.fasaNJurusan4LWBP = fasaNJurusan4LWBP;

    this.RSLWBP = RSLWBP;
    this.STLWBP = STLWBP;
    this.TRLWBP = TRLWBP;
    this.RNLWBP = RNLWBP;
    this.SNLWBP = SNLWBP;
    this.TNLWBP = TNLWBP;


    this.fasaRUtamaWBP = fasaRUtamaWBP;
    this.fasaRJurusan1WBP = fasaRJurusan1WBP;
    this.fasaRJurusan2WBP = fasaRJurusan2WBP;
    this.fasaRJurusan3WBP = fasaRJurusan3WBP;
    this.fasaRJurusan4WBP = fasaRJurusan4WBP;

    this.fasaSUtamaWBP = fasaSUtamaWBP;
    this.fasaSJurusan1WBP = fasaSJurusan1WBP;
    this.fasaSJurusan2WBP = fasaSJurusan2WBP;
    this.fasaSJurusan3WBP = fasaSJurusan3WBP;
    this.fasaSJurusan4WBP = fasaSJurusan4WBP;

    this.fasaTUtamaWBP = fasaTUtamaWBP;
    this.fasaTJurusan1WBP = fasaTJurusan1WBP;
    this.fasaTJurusan2WBP = fasaTJurusan2WBP;
    this.fasaTJurusan3WBP = fasaTJurusan3WBP;
    this.fasaTJurusan4WBP = fasaTJurusan4WBP;

    this.fasaNUtamaWBP = fasaNUtamaWBP;
    this.fasaNJurusan1WBP = fasaNJurusan1WBP;
    this.fasaNJurusan2WBP = fasaNJurusan2WBP;
    this.fasaNJurusan3WBP = fasaNJurusan3WBP;
    this.fasaNJurusan4WBP = fasaNJurusan4WBP;

    this.tegangangarduRSWBP = tegangangarduRSWBP;
    this.tegangangarduSTWBP = tegangangarduSTWBP;
    this.tegangangarduTRWBP = tegangangarduTRWBP;
    this.tegangangarduRNWBP = tegangangarduRNWBP;
    this.tegangangarduSNWBP = tegangangarduSNWBP;
    this.tegangangarduTNWBP = tegangangarduTNWBP;

    this.teganganujungJaringan1R = teganganujungJaringan1R;
    this.teganganujungJaringan1RIDPel = teganganujungJaringan1RIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan1S = teganganujungJaringan1S;
    this.teganganujungJaringan1SIDPel = teganganujungJaringan1SIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan1T = teganganujungJaringan1T;
    this.teganganujungJaringan1TIDPel = teganganujungJaringan1TIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan2R = teganganujungJaringan2R;
    this.teganganujungJaringan2RIDPel = teganganujungJaringan2RIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan2S = teganganujungJaringan2S;
    this.teganganujungJaringan2SIDPel = teganganujungJaringan2SIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan2T = teganganujungJaringan2T;
    this.teganganujungJaringan2TIDPel = teganganujungJaringan2TIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan3R = teganganujungJaringan3R;
    this.teganganujungJaringan3RIDPel = teganganujungJaringan3RIDPel;


    this.teganganujungJaringan3S = teganganujungJaringan3S;
    this.teganganujungJaringan3SIDPel = teganganujungJaringan3SIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan3T = teganganujungJaringan3T;
    this.teganganujungJaringan3TIDPel = teganganujungJaringan3TIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan4R = teganganujungJaringan4R;
    this.teganganujungJaringan4RIDPel = teganganujungJaringan4RIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan4S = teganganujungJaringan4S;
    this.teganganujungJaringan4SIDPel = teganganujungJaringan4SIDPel;

    this.teganganujungJaringan4T = teganganujungJaringan4T;
    this.teganganujungJaringan4TIDPel = teganganujungJaringan4TIDPel;



}
```

Comment: Is this necessary to pass these too many parameters in constructor? You can only put one array of string and one array of integer and pass those two arrays as parameters. And in the functional process, you can process the arrays to get those fields value. I am not sure about your full intention. If you can explain, then probably it would be easier for other to help you.

Comment: Why do you need to pass so many values (325, AFAICS) to the constructor when you only assign 4 of them to fields?

Comment: Sorry I'm sort of new with Java. No, actually it is not four. I'll edit the code

Comment: I can not put it more as the form limited into 30000 characters, but I've put some, it is actually will be all of those

Comment: Thank you mahbubur rahman, can you help me with example

Comment: @CharlieBrown I have added a sample constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this code just for a sample.
    public class TooManyParams {

```
private int a;
private int b;
private int c;

private int d;

private String e;
private String f;
private String g;
private String h;
private String i;

public TooManyParams() {
    super();
}

public TooManyParams(int intvalues[], String strvalues[]) {

    this.a = intvalues[0];
    this.b = intvalues[1];
    this.c = intvalues[2];
    this.d = intvalues[3];

    this.e= strvalues[0];
    this.f= strvalues[1];
    this.g= strvalues[2];
    this.h= strvalues[3];
    this.i= strvalues[4];

    System.out.println("too many params can be accumulated to a small set of params"+this.a+this.b+this.c+this.d+this.e+this.f+this.g+this.h+this.i);

 }

public static void main(String args[]){
    int intParams[]={1,2,3,4};
    String strParams[]={"a","b","c","d","e"};
    TooManyParams tmp=new TooManyParams(intParams,strParams);
}
}
```